# EF Auditing Constrained Values?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, audit

I have auditing code setup in my SaveChanges() method which captures any changes on an entity and stores an audit record in the database. However, some properties are simply integer foreign keys which mean nothing to a user if they saw that previously a foreign key was 5 and now it's 9. Instead, I would like to be able to dictate what is returned when the foreign key property is accessed for it's value. I.e. auditing the PersonId property actually returns the forename + surname + dob.

My initial though was to set the getter of the property to return the value, but this would cause problems elsewhere where the actual id needs returning.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is making a partial class an option ? If so you could code another property of your entity and make it return whatever you want.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier What do you mean by another property? My audit works by comparing the values in the properties compared to how they stood previously, any changes means the changed properties are accessed and their new and old values records. It uses reflection.

Comment: Have you seen [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#auditnet) with its [EF](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#auditentityframework) extension? Maybe you can use a [Custom Action](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions)
to add the information you want to the audit.